# When I try to save data from table to another by datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview, insert-into

I have a datagridview read data from (t1) and I want to save data into another  table (t2) with a procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[saving_tasks]
    @task1 nvarchar(50),
    @task2 nvarchar(50),
    @task3 nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
    insert into t2 (task1, task2, task3)
    values (@task1, @task2, @task3)
end
```

[image]

And using this code to saving data  from (t1. col1) checked rows to (t2.task1  and t2.task2  and t2.task3)

```
Dim comm As New SqlCommand
    comm.Connection = sqlconn
    comm.CommandText = "saving_task"
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task1", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task2", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task3", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            'Else'

        End If

    Next
    sqlconn.Open()
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

And when I try to save I get error on the line `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Could you add the exact error messge received? And why do you save the value of Cells(1) for every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error in your query is the fact that you call ExecuteNonQuery only after the end of the loop. This executes the command only one time and not for every row, so the main fix is to move the ExecuteNonQuery inside the loop.

However, if you try to reuse the same command for every row in your grid, you need to avoid adding the same parameter to the same command. You need to call

```
 comm.Parameters.Clear()
```

before adding the same parameters in the loop, but you can also define the parameters before entering the loop and just change the value at each loop

```
Dim comm As New SqlCommand
comm.Connection = sqlconn
comm.CommandText = "saving_task"
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
comm.Parameters.Add("@task1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)        
comm.Parameters.Add("@task2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)    
comm.Parameters.Add("@task3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)    
sqlconn.Open()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
        comm.Parameters("@task1").Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        comm.Parameters("@task2").Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        comm.Parameters("@task3").Value = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Next
sqlconn.Close()
```

(Notice that I suppose you have a typo in the index of the cell to save)

Comment: i call the same cell because I want to take the value from the same column from first table and save this values in one row in second table

Comment: when I try this code :
  comm.Parameters("@task1").Value = DGV1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value
comm.Parameters("@task1").Value = DGV1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value
It work but I want to make it run in all rows that I checked

Comment: That's the reason for your check on the Cell(0) Do you mean that the code updates all the rows also the unchecked ones?

Comment: Sorry but then I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: the problem is 
I want the loop run on cell(0) to check if it checked or not and then get the value from checked rows only and put the values in second table in 1 row
but when I use this code :
comm.Parameters("@task1").Value = DGV1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value 
It's gives me fixed value

Comment: I hope you understand what is the problem

Comment: You should use the indexer variable `i` to reference the Rows collection not the fixed value 1

Comment: ok that what I try to do with this code :
 Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task1", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task2", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("task3", DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        End If

Comment: but it's give this  error on (comm.ExecuteNonQuery()) :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Procedure or function saving_tasks has too many arguments specified.

Comment: It is pointless that we continue this discussion if you don't write the code that I have given. Look at my code. **The parameters are declared outside the loop. Inside the loop I change only the Value.** If you call AddWithValue inside the loop your command has 3 parameters in the first loop, 6 on the second loop, 9 on the third one and so on...

Comment: It's working and saving data but there is a problem when when saving data It's Repeat the same choices 3 times in the row
and create row for every choice 
example : **task1 | task1 | task1 in row
                   task2 | task2 | task2 in another row **

Comment: This happens if you have set the three parameters with the same `Cell(1).Value` as you do in your initial code.. As you can see, in my code I use `Cells(1).Value, Cells(2).Value, Cells(3).Value` for the three parameters. So I should get the values `a1, b1,d1`, then at the second checked row I get `a3,b3,d3` and so on...

Comment: you are right but I want to get the values from the first column only when I check get values 'a1, a3 , a4 in second table in one row